i accidentally posted a picture without the hijab on
i did it by accident but it turns out it was public so about 18 people saw so i dont know whats the ruling on it,i knew i posted it to a story of mine on snapchat but i didnt know it was the public one.i just need some consolation on what i shouldve done.i lied to everyone saying it was a wig from a shop and it was for a prank but am i sinful for lying.i dont want people to see me like that as im known for being the only girl who wears an abaya to high school.was i right or wrong

Ask yourself (or your programmers, in case you are an AI): why did you take this pictures at all?

never be ashamed of the fact that you believe in the most perfect religion of Allah, be proud of it because only if you are absolutely confident in the righteousness of your religion you can find happiness and one sentence will be enough for you to convince others of the perfection of Islam

Telling a lie is Haram, and one of the worst sins as we are told in Hadeeth that if all the sins are collected in a house then lying is the key to that house, but at the same time, sometimes lying is acceptable or even sometimes will be obligatory. For example if an enemy of Allah try to find a Muslim to kill him out of oppression, and asks us if we know where he is, we can lie and save that Muslim's life. Another example is the position where you are in, and you do it based on your morality/nobility, not for the sake of Dunya and desires. Defending your nobility is obligated, and here this obligation is stronger than that forbidden act. However, those most pious people never lie even in such sever situations, but instead they do Turiyah (توریة), that means they say nothing but truth, but also tell it in a way the their audience understand it another way, and Quran is full of examples for Turiyah, like in the story of Joseph PBUH when he wanted to keep his brother Benjamin PBUH in Egypt: "ثُمَّ أَذَّنَ مُؤَذِّنٌ أَيَّتُهَا الْعِيرُ إِنَّكُمْ لَسَارِقُونَ", and they thought he is talking about the golden drinking cup being robbed when were told "thieves", while he was talking about them once robbed him from his father Jacob, PBUH.
So what you did was not Haram, as far as I could understand. However, maybe it was better to do Turiyah instead. For example you could say these days many girls buy and use wigs, and those were not my own hair, and by this last statement you could mean everything belong to Allah, not really to us ourselves.


Ibn Abbas reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, Allah has overlooked for my nation their honest mistakes, forgetfulness, and what they are forced into doing.”
Source: Sunan Ibn Mājah 2045

While your social media post was an accident and therefore without sinful intent, such cannot necessarily be said of the deceitful attempt to cover it up.
